# How to clear the cache for a cluster?

Tags: dolphindb

How to clear the cache for a cluster?

I want to clear the cache for a cluster. Can the function `clearAllCache()` be used for to clear the cache for each nodes in a cluster?

Answer (score 0):

getSessionMemoryStat() can be used to check the amount of memory used if the systems appears out of memory. The function clearAllCache() can be used for manually clearing the cached data of the nodes.